# YSlow: no character set specified in their HTTP headers

Tags: .htaccess

```
The following resources have no character set specified in their HTTP headers. 
Specifying a character set in HTTP headers can speed up browser rendering.

http://www.mysite.com/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto300.woff
http://www.mysite.com/assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto700.woff
http://www.mysite.com/assets/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

How can I fix it via .htaccess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding these 2 lines in your .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .htm .html .css .js .woff
```

Comment: I have entered AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 but still, I get the warning!